# System of equation, value of $a$ and more than one solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I've the following problem.

For which value of *a* do the system of equation have more then one solution? Write the complete solutions for all value of *a*.

\begin{matrix}
x+ay+z=1\\ 
ax+y+z=a+1 \\ 
x-y+z=a+2 
\end{matrix}

It gives the following.
\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a  &1\\ 
a &1  &1 \\ 
1 &-1  & 1
\end{vmatrix}

$$
detA=1-a^2\\
a=\pm1
$$

If a=1, which is not a solution.
\begin{vmatrix}
1 &1  &1|1\\ 
1 &1  &1|2\\ 
1 &-1  & 1|3
\end{vmatrix}

If a=-1.
\begin{vmatrix}
1 &-1  &1|1\\ 
-1 &1  &1|0\\ 
1 &-1  & 1|1
\end{vmatrix}

\begin{vmatrix}
1 &-1  &1|1\\ 
0 &0  &2|1\\ 
0 &0  & 0|0
\end{vmatrix}
$$z=1/2$$

How do i proceed?

The answer shall be:
$$
a=-1. (x,y,z)=(t+1/2,\ t,\ 1/2).
$$

EDIT:
$$
y=t\\
x-t+1/2=1 \Rightarrow x=t+1/2 \\
t+1/2-y+1/2=1 \Rightarrow y=t
$$

My conclussion is: The value $a=1$ have the complete solution $(x,y,z)=(t+1/2,\ t,\ 1/2)$. The use of *t* mean that it's value is infinite.

Comment: The fact that the determinant is $0$ says that **either** there is an infinity of solutions, **either** there is no solutions. You have to check the two values you found. For $a=1$, the two first equations become $x+y+z=1$ and $x+y+z=2$... What can you say ?

Comment: Thanks for explaining what determinant equal to 0 means.

$ 1\neq2\ $
Therefore $ a=1 $ doesn't have any solution.

Comment: For the particular values of a(-1) and z(1/2), all three equations are essentially the same x-y=1/2, allowing any x and y with that difference.

Comment: For infinite solutions, by Cramer's Rule, we have $∆=∆_x=∆_y=∆_z=0$.

Comment: @user9060784 Yes, you got it for $a=1$. Now, for $a=-1$, your system is equivalent, as you wrote, to the system $x-y+z=1$ and $z=1/2$. You can see that **for every** value of $y$, there is a value of $x$ and a value of $z$ that give a solution. So you have an infinity of solutions, and you can express all of them depending of a parameter, called $t$, corresponding to the value of $y$.